# Listing (detecting) closures in a method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, closures

I know I can iterate through all locally defined variables in a method using MethodInfo.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables.

But if I define a method as:

```
public static void somemethod( int someint )
{
    int test = 1;

    HM.M(() =>
    {
        test = 2;
    });
}
```

The anonymous method can access someint and test as closures, but GetMethodBody().LocalVariables will be empty.

Is there a way to use reflection to detect the closures?

Comment: If you inspect the IL you will find the compiler creates an instance of a compiler generated class like `Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'`, but Reflection doesn't give you the tools to do that kind of thing. You could probably do it with Mono.Cecil or [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/).

Comment: I have researched the first a little, and so far I think Mono.Cecil can´t do it. I´ll research a little further, and I´ll also look into System.Reflection.Metadata, tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. A closure in c# is implemented by the compiler with a compiler-generated class. The compiler generates a class where it copies all variables that will be accessible in the method, and the method itself is encapsulated in this class. The external variables values are copied to the class.

So, in my example above, the M method has the signature:

```
public void M( Action method )
```

The steps to get the list of closures are:

```
MethodInfo mi = method.Method; 

FieldInfo[] fields = mi.DeclaringType.GetFields
                                    (
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                        BindingFlags.Instance |
                                        BindingFlags.Public |
                                        BindingFlags.Static
                                    );
```

DeclaringType will be the compiler-generated class used to implement the closures.

In the fields array all closures will be listed.

<s>To get the VALUES of the closures is another story, but it is not part of this question.</s>

EDIT:
As pointed out by @leppie, get the values is easy:

```
object res = fields[ 0 ].GetValue( method.Target );
```

Comment: Actually much easier. Just check the `Target` property of the delegate. You can also get the values from that instance.

Comment: You may want to improve your answer in that case :)

Comment: @leppie: Since I didn´t include getting the values in the question, technically the answer is ok, I think. I need a list of closures, so using DeclaringType or Target is equivalent in this case, but you´re right, improving the answer will not harm.